# ODBC connection to LimeSurvey and Excel

Tags: odbc, limesurvey

I want to connect excel through a ODBC connection to the database of individual surveys in LimeSurvey is this possible? I have looked in the manual and Googled but have found nothing.

Or if not ODBC is there another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you let us know what you want to achieve by connecting excel with limesurvey database, it will be more clear to answer your question. I guess you would be more interested in the Excel export feature in LimeSurvey than ODBC connection?

However, coming to your question, I have tried connecting LimeSurvey db with MS Access using ODBC. And I think you should be able to do the same with MS Excel.

Comment: Thank you Amit for your comments but I have let go of this approach as unfeasible.